# How to position video options on video tag in HTML?

Tags: html, css, video, position

I have a position problem about video tag in HTML :

[image]

My question is why my options translating to left top not in original position?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read this, revise your question accordingly and add the code as a snippet:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: By the way , maybe it is conflicted by different framework.